# How to expect a float number or just a number in a React test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing-library

I have the following code:

```
it('should return a number', async () => {
  const exchangeRate = await getExchangeRate('USD','HUF')
  expect(exchangeRate).toBe()
})
```

How can I build this test so that I can use the `expect()` method to check if the `exchangeRate` const is a **float number** or just a **number** ? ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert the type of the value by using `typeof`:

`expect(typeof exchangeRate === 'number').toBe(true)`

Answer (score 1):

You can assert on the following

```
   expect(Number.isInteger(exchangeRate)).toBe(true); // This will be true if its a Integer else it will be false for float.
```

To further add some more checks you can do the following:

```
  expect(!isNaN(exchangeRate) && Number.isInteger(exchangeRate)).toBe(true); // Check for Integer
  expect(!isNaN(exchangeRate) && !Number.isInteger(exchangeRate)).toBe(true); // Check for Float
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript there is only 1 numeric type: [`number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). Both *int (whole)* values and *float (fractional)* values are stored using the **`number`** type.

It is possible to check if a number is a whole value by using `Number.isInteger(x)`, however this will return true also if your float happens to be `3.00000....` - which is a totally valid float value, while also being exactly the same as the "integer" value `3`.

In this case you probably would want to use `typeof x == 'number' && !isNaN(x)` which will return true for all "float" values, inclusing for those values that happen to be "integer" values.